# s3Hook load_file_obj FileObj must implement read Error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow

I have tried everything I can find and think of, but cannot seem to get this code right. 
I'm using `Airflow`, trying to run a SQL select statement, return the results, and upload them directly to `s3` using a `PythonCallable task`.

I am unable to save the DataFrame as a csv locally, so that is not an option. 
Ultimately, I keep looping back to this `ERROR - Fileobj must implement read`. The only "successful" attempts have produced empty results in my s3 file. I tried using the `.seek(0)` method that I found in another post, but then I got `ERROR - Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`. Anyway, below is my code. Any direction is enormously appreciated.

```
    snow_hook = SnowflakeHook(
        snowflake_conn_id='Snowflake_ETL_vault'
    )
    df = snow_hook.get_pandas_df(sql=sql)
    with io.StringIO() as stream:
        df.to_csv(stream)
        stream.seek(0)
        f = stream.getvalue()

        s3_hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id='s3_analytics')
        s3_hook.load_file_obj(
            file_obj=f,
            bucket_name=bkt,
            key=key,
            replace=True
        )
```

Edit: I have also tried `f = stream.read()` and still somehow get Fileobj must implement read.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue and spent some time in understanding the nature of the issue.

The reason why you are getting **ERROR - Fileobj must implement read** is that `file_obj` expects stream object itself not `stream.getvalue()`

And pandas.to_csv having some encoding issues, you can find the issue details here
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23854

The workaround is write bytes using load_bytes function from s3hook

```py
with io.BytesIO() as buffer:                                
    buffer.write(
        bytes(
            df.to_csv(None, sep="|", quotechar='"'),
            encoding="utf-8"
        )
    )               
    hook.load_bytes(
        buffer.getvalue(),
        bucket_name="bucket_name",
        key="keyname.csv", 
        replace=True
    )
```

I am still looking for a better solution though

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like through the `load_string` command

```
        df = snow_hook.get_pandas_df(sql=sql)
        csv_data_as_str = df.to_csv(index=False)
        s3_hook.load_string(string_data=csv_data_as_str, key=s3_key, bucket_name=s3_bucket, replace=True)
```