# Load parquet file to S3 from Airflow without using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet, pyarrow

I was wondering if there was a direct way of uploading a parquet file to S3 without using pandas.

I'm using pyarrow and Airflow's S3Hook class. I have a pyarrow.Table object but I cannot find any method or function to upload the file to S3. I'm trying to use buffer options but to no avail.

```
        writer = pa.BufferOutputStream()
        pq.write_table(pt, writer) #pt is the parquet table
        body = bytes(writer.getvalue())
        
        s3_hook.load_file_obj(
            file_obj=body,
         key='LoginAppWeb/login_app_web_{}.parquet'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')),
            bucket_name=var_ambt["S3_OUTPUT_BUCKET"],
            replace=True
        )
```

Which yields: `ValueError: Fileobj must implement read`

Comment: Might be relevant: [s3Hook load_file_obj FileObj must implement read Error - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517666/s3hook-load-file-obj-fileobj-must-implement-read-error)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thank you. Can you plaease post this as a reply to the post so I can select it as the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think [load_file_obj](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/hooks/S3_hook/index.html#airflow.hooks.S3_hook.S3Hook.load_file_obj) expects a file like object, not bytes.

You can try to use `BytesIO`:

```py
with io.BytesIO() as body:
    pq.write_table(body, writer)
    body.seek(0)
    
    s3_hook.load_file_obj(
        file_obj=body,
        key='LoginAppWeb/login_app_web_{}.parquet'.format(
            datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')),
        bucket_name=var_ambt["S3_OUTPUT_BUCKET"],
        replace=True
    )
```